# Do you recognize this connector?

Tags: nissan, part-identification

I bought a pair of side marker lamps for my car (OEM p/n 26160-JK00B). They are compatible with Nissan MO/Infinity.
[image: Front view]
[image: Connector view]
[image]

My car is a Nissan Murano 2009 (US model) which doesn't come by default with these flashers so I have to install them by myself.

The original headlamp harness doesn't come with connectors for these side marker lamps so I have to wire myself this thing (a wire extension from the front headlight - the turn lamp - to this side marker lamp).

But the question is: what connector should I buy/use in order to connect this lamp properly? Of course I can crimp two [female spade connectors](http://snag.gy/xzlta.jpg) and then to hook them to the lamp but I would opt for a waterproof connector that fits, if possible.

Maybe someone, a handy auto electrician - anyone, has a clue about what could possible fit into that socket.

Comment: Cut one off a junkyard car.

Answer (score 6):

You will be able to get the pigtail from the dealer. It's the connector and about 12 inches of wire. They are used to repair harnesses.

Answer (score 4):

Lol, I had forgot about this post :-)
I figured out finally what connector I needed: Z03FBR manufactured by Mitsubishi.
I was able to find them in Japan at this seller: http://www.best-sys.com/products/detail.php?product_id=92

The website is only in Japanese so knowing little bit of kanji would help :-)

So I bought the parts separately (the female, the male, the housing) then I just used some wire I already had at home and I manufactured the whole assembly myself.

PS: they could be found probably at any Nissan dealer in US (eg. [courtesyparts.com](http://www.courtesyparts.com/24342q-connector-assy-harness-repair3p-sentra-b13-08/1990-door-door-f/fr-turn-signal-lamp-z03fbr-1993-1994-p-81395.html))